# scanf string in c - why can i scan more than the char[] declaration?

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I have a program where I need to scanf a string, which I know it will be only 2 characters long. (for example: "ex").
what is the proper way to do that?

I was going for:

```
char myStr[3];
scanf("%s", myStr);
```

It works just fine, but when I enter a 10-letter word it also works just fine. How come? Does the [3] has no meaning? How should I do this the proper way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It works just fine, but when I enter a 10-letter word it also works
>   just fine.

It only appears to work fine but it's actually undefined behaviour. That is because `scanf` stores the characters it reads from `stdin` into the buffer pointed to by `myStr`. The size of `myStr` is `3`. Therefore, there's space for only `2` characters. One character space is saved for the terminating null byte to mark the end of the string which is added by `scanf` automatically. When the input string is longer than `2` characters, `scanf` overruns the buffer accessing memory out of the bound of the array. It is illegal to access memory out of the array bound and invokes undefined behaviour.

The next time, it may very well crash. It's unpredictable and you should always avoid it.
To guard against it, you should specify maximum field width for the conversion specifier `%s` in the format string of `scanf`. It should be one less than the array size to accommodate the terminating null byte.

```
 char myStr[3];
 scanf("%2s", myStr);
```

Better still, I suggest you to use `fgets`.

```
char myStr[3];
// read and store at most one less than 
// sizeof(myStr) chars
fgets(myStr, sizeof myStr, stdin);
```

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to limit the input using `scanf()` is

```
if (scanf("%2s", myStr) != 1) /* error */;
```

But consider using `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`

```
if (fgets(myStr, sizeof myStr, stdin) == NULL) /* error */;
```

Answer (score 2):

> but when I enter a 10-letter word it also works just fine. How come? Does the [3] has no meaning?

I doesn't work fine. See in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char second[5] = "BBBB";
  char myStr[3] = {0};

  scanf("%s", myStr);

  printf("second = %s\n", second);
  printf("myStr  = %s\n", myStr);

  return 0;
}
```

writing only two characters in `myStr` is fine:

```
a.exe
AA
second = BBBB
myStr  = AA
```

writing more data overrides the near by memory of `second`:

```
a.exe
AAAAAAA
second = AAAA
myStr  = AAAAAAA
```

You need to limit the number of characters `scanf` reads using something like 
`scanf("%2s", myStr);`, `2` is the size of `myStr - 1`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that when you write past your buffer like this, the results are _undefined behavior_. In this specific case you've defined what will happen through experimentation or just knowledge of your environment, but change the compiler or compiler options or operating system (which implies changing compiler) and the fault might manifest differently and it might not even be obvious what happened.

Comment: Thanks. And in that case if I use scanf("%2s",myStr) then how should the myStr declaration look like?

Comment: @DorShalom `char myStr[3]`, the extra character is for the null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

You can´t do that.
scanf will do nothing to prevent it, but it can (or, in larger programs, *will*)
lead to problems later on. Like unexpectly changed variable values, program crashes...

Use fgets

Comment: And yet, scant can do something to prevent it if you ask it too... see @pmg's answer to learn how to ask it to ;)   [Not my down vote, but this is probably why it was issued.]